# Vectors with constraints

Tags: matlab, vector, constraints

I am working for my dissertation on MATLAB and I have the following problem:
I have a vector (`Pbat = zeros(8760,1);`) and this vector, depending on two other vectors (`Pgen` and `Pload`), should change as follows:

```
for i=1:length(Pload) 
    if i==1
        Pbat(i) = 1000;
    else
        if Pload(i) < Pgen(i)     %// Battery charging
            if Pbat(i) < Pbat_max && Pbat(i) > Pbat_min
                Pbat(i) = (Pbat(i-1)+(Pgen(i)-Pload(i));
            else
                Pbat(i) = Pbat(i-1);
            end
        elseif Pload(i) > Pgen(i)   %// Battery discharging
            if Pbat(i) < Pbat_max && Pbat(i) > Pbat_min
                Pbat(i) = (Pbat(i-1)-(Pload(i)-Pgen(i));
            else
                Pbat(i) = Pbat(i-1);
            end
        else
            Pbat(i) = Pbat(i-1);
        end
    end
end
```

However, the `Pbat` should be for all the values that it could get in respect constraints like `Pbat_min <= Pbat(i) <= Pbat_max`.

When I run the above code I get a constant value. This value is `1000` (happens when`i==1`).

Comment: It would help if you would explain the logic in words instead of just uncommented code

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see with your code is that you check if `Pbat(i)` is within the limits `[Pbat_min, Pbat_max]` *before* you calculate `Pbat(i)`. As `Pbat` is initialized as 0, in this check, `Pbat(i)` will always be zero and the test will probably fail (if `Pbat_min>0`).

Now a different comment: To calculate `Pbat(i)`, you either add `(Pgen(i) - Pload(i))` or subtract `(Pload(i) - Pgen(i))`. This is the exact same operation (simple mathematics). Further, if that difference is zero, you add nothing - still the same operation. You can thus calculate `Pbat(i)` by

```
Pbat(i) = Pbat(i-1) + (Pgen(i) - Pload(i));
```

To include the charging efficiency `n` as described in a comment to this answer, we need some more logic, as it only applies if `Pgen(i) > Pload(i)`, i.e. when charging. For this we can e.g. introduce an augmented efficiency

```
nAug = [1, n];
```

which means: when discharging, the efficiency is `1`, when charging it is `n`. Now we can multiply our difference by the first element (`1`) if `Pgen(i) <= Pload(i)` or multiply it by the second element (`n`) otherwise. For this we use the logical expression `Pgen(i)>Pload(i)`, which returns `0` (first case) or `1` (second case) and add `1`, so we can use it to logically index the augmented vector `nAug`:

```
Pbat(i) = Pbat(i-1) + nAug((Pgen(i)>Pload(i))+1) * (Pgen(i) - Pload(i));
```

After calculating this, you can check, if `Pbat(i)` is within the bounds and set it to the boundary value otherwise:

```
 if Pbat(i) > Pbat_max
     Pbat(i) = Pbat_max;
 elseif Pbat(i) < Pbat_min
     Pbat(i) = Pbat_min;
 end
```

Everything set together gives you:

```
for i=1:length(Pload) 
    if i==1
        Pbat(i) = 1000;
    else
        % Calculate next value
        Pbat(i) = Pbat(i-1) + nAug((Pgen(i)>Pload(i))+1) * (Pgen(i) - Pload(i));

        % Check bounds
        if Pbat(i) > Pbat_max
            Pbat(i) = Pbat_max;
        elseif Pbat(i) < Pbat_min
            Pbat(i) = Pbat_min;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! Last thing is when the `Pload(i) < Pgen(i)` the `Pbat(i) = Pbat(i-1) + n*(Pgen(i) - Pload(i));`. Because there is a charging efficiency less than unit due to losses. How can I write this keeping your writing format?

Comment: I revised my answer to include that. Hope this solution works for you!

Comment: one upvote for a nice detailed answer, and to make up for the recent plagiarism you were just victim above ...

Answer (score 1):

You initialise `Pbat` to zeros, then, for every `i` you check if the current `Pbat(i)` is within the allowed range:

`if Pbat(i) < Pbat_max && Pbat(i) > Pbat_min`

I'm not sure what value you have for `Pbat_min`, but I guess it's safe to assume that it is non-negative, so this statement will fail for all values of `i`.

Comment: That was true, I changed it.